# Как поменть цвет шрифтов и фона вокруг текста консольной программы?

Tags: linux, c

Как в Си поменять цвет шрифтов и фона вокруг текста консольной линукс-программы?

Comment: Всё зависит от вашего окружения: ОС, что (какая библиотека) используется для вывода, и т.д.  Без указаня этих данных вопрос смысла не имеет. (но в любом случае могу дать подсказку: ответ есть в  документации к вашей библиотеке для консольного вывода. Сначала загляните в неё, и если там что-то будет непонятно - уже сюда)

Comment: Делал когда-то. [Вот](http://pastebin.com/UqQPdN2z) тут (все в одном файле color.h) набор макросов и пример.

Answer (score 1):

Вот тут хорошо описано как:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148/colorizing-your-terminal-and-shell-environment

ПО аналогии реализовывал на php.

```
private function getMsgFormat($msg, $color = FALSE , $printDate = TRUE )
    {
        $colorTag = ($color ? (isset($this->fontColor[$color]) ? "\033[" . $this->fontColor[$color] . "m" : "" ) : "");
        $lockTag = ($colorTag ? "\033[0m" : "");
        $patern = "{color}".($printDate ? "[" . date("y.m d-h:i:s") . " ] \t " : "")."$msg{lock} \n ";
        return array(
            str_replace(array("{color}", "{lock}"), array($colorTag, $lockTag), $patern),
            str_replace(array("{color}", "{lock}"), "", $patern),
        );

    }

private function cmdColor()
    {
        $this->fontColor['black'] = '0;30';
        $this->fontColor['blue'] = '0;34';
        $this->fontColor['green'] = '0;32';
        $this->fontColor['red'] = '0;31';
        $this->fontColor['yellow'] = '1;33';
        $this->fontColor['white'] = '1;37';

        $this->backColor['black'] = '40';
        $this->backColor['red'] = '41';
        $this->backColor['green'] = '42';
        $this->backColor['yellow'] = '43';
        $this->backColor['blue'] = '44';
    }
```

Comment: Какое отношение это имеет к языку `C`?

Comment: Если надо раскрасить консольный вывод , то важен сам принцип построения самого терминального вывода, а он в данном случае везде одинаков.